# Require unimplemented interfaces as parameters to business layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, interface, refactoring, viewmodel

**Does it smell bad to require a consumer to implement an interface just to pass parameters?**

---

Just to help visualize, my specific situation is an ASP.NET C# MVC website, with the following assembly contents:

```
MyWebAssembly.Web
    Controllers
MyWebAssembly.Models
    PurchaseViewModel : IBillingAddress
        SubscribeViewModel : PurchaseViewModel
        AddCreditsViewModel : PurchaseViewModel
MyWebAssembly.BLL
    IBillingAddress
    BeginPurchase(IBillingAddress, etc.)
MyWebAssembly.Data
    Models
```

I have roughly 100 ViewModels that were tightly coupled with my business logic. I've extracted these to interfaces (as shown above) to avoid adding yet another layer of identical models to automap, now that I'm finally separating my business layer from the website.

I suppose it's a fine first step in this process. This allowed me to move the business logic out of the assembly, but I feel dirty, like all I did is shuffle code around. Not all of my ViewModels are this coupled, but IBillingAddress is just one of multiple examples.

**Do you think it's bad form to require a consumer to implement an interface just to pass parameters?** I feel like I'm back in Win32 API days when I do that. Should I just pass 10 more standard type parameters to my business method? Is there some obvious pivot to my architecture I'm overlooking?

---

Edit:

I'm still giving this some thought. Perhaps one of the reasons that this example confuses me is because BillingAddress seems like a relatively fixed interface to depend on. It makes more sense to expose it and build it into a ViewModel. I guess if it were a potentially moving target (like ICustomer, for example) a mapped interaction would make more sense. Your advice is still desired.